# Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform

Tags: java, flutter, dart, android-studio, gradle

i just created a hello_world flutter project and got those errors :

```
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart:5:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
       ^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app_bar_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.     
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/arc.dart:6:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/badge_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.       
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/banner_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.      
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_app_bar_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_navigation_bar_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart:5:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.      
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
```

just in case :
jdk version : 20
gradle version : 8.6
it should be compatible since 8.3 it is
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.6-all.zip

i've been searching for almost two days now and i didn't solve this issue
i would really appreaciate some help !

Comment: Did you use `flutter create` to create your project?  Post your `pubspec.yaml` file.

Answer (score -1):

flutter upgrade, clean, pub get didn't work
fd :
tried that and it didn't work
fd :

```
Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3155], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.19.1 on channel stable at C:\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision abb292a07e (5 days ago), 2024-02-20 14:35:05 -0800
    • Engine revision 04817c99c9
    • Dart version 3.3.0
    • DevTools version 2.31.1

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-VanillaIceCream, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.9.1)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.9.34616.47
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22621.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314)

[√] VS Code (version 1.86.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.82.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3155]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 122.0.6261.69
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 121.0.2277.128

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```

Comment: This is not an answer.  If you want to update your question, you can *edit* your question.  You also haven't answered the questions I asked in the comments.

Comment: This is not an answer. If you want to share your progress, you can edit your question and add more information below the initial information you have written.